# How to solve this problem?

Tags: android

> 06-15 00:26:25.709:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26573): Caused
>   by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>   no such table:

I m getting table not found error while running the application in emulator its working fine if i install the apk in the device its not working

Comment: At least show some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because, sqlite databases and tables will not be shifted when you change environments. For example when you work on emulator, you could have created a sqlite table using Sqlite manager or some other application and inserted into the database folder of your app. But when you put the .apk file into the mobile, this table will not be shifted to your mobile. So better don't try to push a already created table into the device, instead try creating a new table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a table in your `SQLite` Database. Then you can run your application.